# Replace css attribute with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scripting

How i can replace the width in below code with a variable value?

```
$('<div/>', {
  'class': "formErrorContent",
   width: '13px',
   text: promptText
}).appendTo(prompt);
```

Like

```
 var promptWidth = (promptText.length * 5) - (promptText.length/2);
 var promtWidthString  = promptWidth + 'px;'
 var promptContent = $('<div/>', { 'class': "formErrorContent", style: 'width:' +   promtWidthString , text: promptText}).appendTo(prompt);
```

The above code will end up in a extra

> < /br >

at end of the promtText

Comment: Have you tried [less](http://lesscss.org/)?

Comment: nope not working with myvar+'px'

Comment: Is there a reason the width has to be a variable within the JS instead of being controlled by CSS (either via media queries or the use of multiple classes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `appendTo` there is no need to store the object in a variable. you can use `width` for setting `width` style to the element, also remove the `+` from your code, note that if you are adding markup, instead of text, you should use  `html`.

```
$('<div/>', { 
    'class': "formErrorContent", 
     width: promtWidthString,
     html: promptText
}).appendTo(prompt);
```

Comment: @PeteEngineer Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: var promptWidth = (promptText.length * 5) - (promptText.length/2);

            var promtWidthString  = promptWidth+'px';
        
            var promptContent = $('<div/>', { 'class': "formErrorContent", width: promtWidthString , text: promptText}).appendTo(prompt);

Comment: i dont know how to make a jsfiddele

Comment: @PeteEngineer Just copy/paste your code and hit save/update http://jsfiddle.net/Urr2c/2/

Comment: what happened is < B R / > was there before in the variable promptText but it was not showing up...but when i change to above code from my old code like below ... < br /> started showing up at run time in the webpage other wise it was not there

Comment: this was teh codew which i was using earlier :  var promptContent = $('<div>').addClass("formErrorContent").
                                html(promptText).appendTo(prompt);